# make another windows won't open if a windows already open tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I want to make only one new window popup opened and block other button process that try to open another windows popup except if that window popup already closed.
there's my sample code:

Home.py

```
from tkinter import *
from cekWin import ui1,ui2,ui3
from GUI1 import GUI1
from GUI2 import GUI2
from GUI3 import GUI3

class Home(GUI1,GUI2,GUI3):
    def HomeMenu():
        ui = Tk()
        buttonUI = Button(ui,text = "Table",command = lambda: Home.process())
        buttonUI.place(x = 90,y = 70)

        buttonUI2 = Button(ui,text = "Input",command = lambda: Home.process2())
        buttonUI2.place(x = 180,y = 70)

        buttonUI3 = Button(ui,text = "Read",command = lambda: Home.process3())
        buttonUI3.place(x = 270,y = 70)

        ui.mainloop()

    def process():
        global ui2
        global ui3
        global ui1
        if ui2 == True:
           print("Another Windows is Opened")
        elif ui3 == True:
           print("Another Windows is Opened")
        else:
           GUI1.Table()
           ui1 = True     

    def process2():
        global ui2
        global ui3
        global ui1
        if ui1 == True:
           print("Another Windows is Opened")
        elif ui3 == True:
           print("Another Windows is Opened")
        else:
           GUI2.Input()
           ui2 = True

    def process3():
        global ui2
        global ui3
        global ui1
        if ui2 == True:
           print("Another Windows is Opened")
        elif ui1 == True:
           print("Another Windows is Opened")
        else:
            GUI3.Read()
            ui3 = True
 Home.HomeMenu()
```

GUI1.py

```
from tkinter import *
from cekWin import *

class GUI1:
    def Table():
        ui = Tk()
        ui.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda:GUI1.doSomething(ui))
        ui.mainloop()
    def doSomething(ui):
        global ui1
        global ui2
        global ui3
        ui1 = False
        ui.destroy()
```

GUI2.py

```
from tkinter import *
from cekWin import *
class GUI2:
    def Input():
        ui = Tk()
        ui.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda:GUI2.doSomething(ui))
        ui.mainloop()
    def doSomething(ui):
        global ui1
        global ui2
        global ui3
        ui2 = False
        ui.destroy()
```

GUI3.py

```
from tkinter import *
from cekWin import *

class GUI3:
    def Read():
        ui = Tk()
        ui.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda:GUI3.doSomething(ui))        
        ui.mainloop()
    def doSomething(ui):
        global ui1
        global ui2
        global ui3
        ui3 = False
        ui.destroy()
```

cekWin.py

```
ui1 = False
ui2 = False
ui3 = False
```

the prosses to lock a button process when there's another window popup opened located at process(),process2(),and process3() on class Home. It's working if I create all of the class in the same file/script ut it won't work if I sparate them. So, what the cause? thank you

Comment: That's too much code if you're asking about creating a window. Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]

Comment: @BryanOakley How about that?

Comment: Still too much. There's no reason to require five files. A simple [mcve] probably wouldn't require more than a couple dozen lines of code, but you've posted 100 lines scattered over five files. Though, all that code does raise a red flag: you have a serious problem in that you should never create more than one instance of `Tk`, and you should never call `mainloop` more than once. Fixing that probably doesn't solve your problem, but we can't adequately answer the question until that problem is fixed.

Comment: Another red flag is your use of globals inside a class.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you want then the below commented script ought to help you:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Ok", command=self.command)
        self.toplevel = Toplevel(self.root) #here we declare the window
        self.button.pack()
        self.toplevel.withdraw() #we hide the window
        self.toplevel.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        #above we overwrite the delete window event (which is triggered when pressing the x) to our own callback
    def command(self):
        self.toplevel.deiconify() #we show the window on button press
    def close(self):
        self.toplevel.withdraw() #we hide the window on close instead of removing it completely

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```